# How to comparatively parse through objects inside a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I have a Person class which contains info `(firstName, lastName, mother, father, siblings, spouse)` and I want to add the people of class Person to a Dictionary.  I would like to comparatively parse through the dictionary to determine the relationship of objects (i.e. Given a person, find their cousins, siblings, etc.).  My question is two fold:
1) How should I set up my Dictionary<...> and 2) How do I access the properties of each Person in the list?  I first tried:

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();  
var human = Person.AddPerson();  // Person.AddPerson() returns a new instance of a Person                               
dictionary.Add(human.name, human)    // setting the key to full name, value to Person object.
```

Should I try something like `Dictionary<string, string>` where `<firstName, lastName>` and once I get all the matches of people with the same name, then start searching the Dictionary for the mother, father, etc.???  This seems terribly slow and not the right way to go.
Edit:  Here is my Person class and one of the other classes (bear in mind I'm just setting this up, I'll handle all the user inputs, etc later):

```
public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set;}
    public Mother mother { get; set; } 
    public Father father { get; set; }
    public Spouse spouse { get; set; }
    public Sibling sibling { get; set; }

    //List<Sibling> siblings = new List<Sibling>();

    public Person()
    { }

    public static Person AddPerson()
    {
        Person newPerson = new Person();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
        newPerson.name = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter mother's name:");
        string input = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        Mother mom = new Mother(input);
        newPerson.mother = mom;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter father's name:");
        string input1 = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        Father dad = new Father(input1);
        newPerson.father = dad;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter sibling's name:");
        string input2 = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        Sibling sib = new Sibling(input2);
        newPerson.sibling = sib;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter spouse's name:");
        string input3 = Console.ReadLine().Trim();
        Spouse partner = new Spouse(input3);
        newPerson.spouse = partner;

        return newPerson;
    }

}

public class Sibling : Person
{
    private string name;
    public Sibling(string Name)
    {
        name = Name;

    }
    public Sibling()
    { }
}

public class Mother : Person
{
    private string name;
    public Mother(string Name)
    {            
        //Mother mom = new Mother();
        name = Name;
    }
    public Mother()
    { }
}

public class Father : Person
{
    private string name;
    public Father(string Name)
    {
        name = Name;

    }
    public Father()
    { }
}

public class Spouse : Person
{
    private string name;
    public Spouse(string Name)
    {
        name = Name;

    }
    public Spouse()
    { }
}

}
```

Comment: Whoops, my Dictionary declaration was:  Dictionary< string, object > dictionary = new Dictionary< string, object >();

Comment: What is your demand?Something you can get a Person object by one of it's properties?

Comment: Why a Dictionary? Sounds like you need a tree data structure.

Comment: Dictionary? I say you would be better off with a non-binary tree data structure.

Comment: I agree that the better solution would be to use a non-binary tree data structure but I was asked to use a Dictionary specifically.  Regarding my problem, I'm thinking I should use Dictionary<string, object> where string would be the full name.  Then I would grab the names I need from that Person's info and search for those people.  Repeat till I had everyone I needed.

Comment: If I implemented a Dictionary<string, object>, how do I access the property info on the object Value?  i.e.:  foreach( KeyValuePair<string, object> person in dictionary)
            {
                if (personSelected.Mother == person.Value.Name????)
                    
            }

Comment: So this is homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: We need to know what types are being used for Mother, Father, Siblings and Spouse.  How about putting your Person class in the question?

Comment: This is not HW, this was a question in an interview for a Software Engineer position

Answer (score 1):

Importantly the `key` of a `dictionary` has to be unique.

So, if you suspect you would have more than one `Person` having the same `first name` then you might not be able to use only the `first name` as the `key`.

Therefore the `key` could be either a combination of `Person` properties like `string.concat(firstName, lastName)` again assuming this combination is unique Or some `random number` (like GUID).

**Edit:**

To help printing you could override your `ToString`, of each class. Below is an example

```
public class Father : Person
    {
        private string name;
        public Father(string Name)
        {
            name = Name;

        }
        public Father()
        { }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
```

This should work then:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", person.Value.father, person.Value.mother, person.Value.sibling);
```

Comment: Ok, I missed this point.  But what would I use as the value?  How do I access the properties of the object stored in the Dictionary?

Comment: `new Dictionary<string, Person>` should be good.. I don't see a reason why you should use `object` (unless you hv asked to)..

Comment: I'm still having issues trying to print out the properties to the Console line of each Person (mom, dad, etc.):                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", person.Key, (Person)person.Value.father, person.Value.mother, person.Value.sibling);

Comment: Never mind I solved it.  I just needed to add another extension:   person.Value.father.name

Comment: @user2359626: hey, sry for the delay.. You could override `ToString` method to help you printing it on the console..

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on using Dictionary,you should define dictionary as `new Dictionary<string, Person>()`,in this way you can loop dictionary like this:

```
foreach (var person in dictionary)
{
    if(person.Value.firstName=="somename")
    // do something
}
```

.
Or you can use `new Dictionary<string, object>()` by convert `object` to `Person` like this

```
foreach (var person in dictionary)
{
    Person _person = (Person)person.Value;
    if(_person.firstName=="somename")
    // do something
}
```

.

I suggest the first solution,the second way will take extra cost on packing and unpacking.

Edit:
my fault

Comment: This won't compile.  You "person" variable will have a `KeyValuePair<string, Person>` in it.

Comment: "Packing and unpacking"? I assume you ment boxing and unboxing, which won't occur here.

Comment: Using KeyValuePair<string, Person> I can't get the (Person)person.Value.Father/Mother/Sibling/Spouse to print:                  Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", person.Key, (Person)person.Value.father, person.Value.mother, person.Value.sibling);  // It just prints out Genealogy.Father, Genealogy.Mother, etc

Comment: How do I print/access the properties (mom,dad,siblings,spouse) to the Console line?